# Rails authentication with jwt and cookies in one app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cookies, jwt

I'm gonna implement new rails app which will provide api for 4 mobile apps and will have web admin part(written with rails ui). I'm considering different approaches to implement auth functionality. For api purposes, I think the jwt approach fits the best. But for web part the cookies are better. Is it a good idea to implement 2 different mechanizm in one app? I'm considering to use devise for cookies and custom implementatuion of jwt for api.

Comment: It is possible, but whether or not it is a good idea, depends entirely on your project

Comment: Thank you for response. The project will be written from scratch, but for existed mobile apps.